# copying last bash command into clipboard

Tags: bash, shell, history

Sometimes I need to save the last typed shell command into the clipboard.
I can do something like this:

```
echo !! | xsel --clipboard
```

Which works successfully.

But when I try to alias the above command:

```
alias echoxs='echo !! | xsel --clipboard'
```

Things do not work as expected. In particular, the clipboard contents become literally `!!`. Obviously, I am missing something about how bash preprocesses commands and aliases. My hope was that an alias, as is intuitive, would be something like a C macro, and that typing the alias would be equivalent to typing its target.

I've tried other approaches and none seem to work. Using `HISTFILE` inside a script does not work because either commands are cached by the shell session and not immediately written to the file, or multiple terminals mess with the file such that the last command in the file is not always reliably the last command in the current session.

```
alias='history 1 | xsel --clipboard'
```

Almost works, except all fails when attempting to modify (eg, cut or sed) the output of history because it is a built-in command.

Is the a way to get the shell's last command through sane stdout?

Comment: I still get literal !!

Comment: FYI, using "doesn't work" in a question title is generally bad form; better to use a phrase that *describes* how it doesn't work (hence the edits).

Comment: bash aliases, unlike csh/tcsh aliases, do not expand parameters. `info bash` and search for `alias` for details.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I did not want to narrow the scope of my question too much into shell aliases, that is why I tried to title it something a bit more generic. For example, possibly a script could have been the answer (it was not). But you are correct. In any case, I should have titled it, "copying last bash command into clipboard"

Comment: I'm curious to know why aliasing doesn't work, but issuing from the terminal does. I encountered the same problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand what you said about "failing when attempting to modify the output of history", so I hope my solution will suit you. I'm using `fc` to get the last command:

```
fc -ln -1 | xsel --clipboard
```

Here are the meaning of the options:

- `l` is to use the standard output
- `n` is to hide the command history number
- `-1` is to get the last command from the history

Comment: did not know about fc

Comment: `fc` is the original history-editing command from ksh; the name stands for "fix command".  The equivalent of `!!` in ksh is "fc -e -" ("fix command with no editor", which just runs the command), usually aliased to "r" for "redo".

Comment: If you're on OSX, a spiffy alias I'd recommend for this is `alias copyLastCmd="fc -ln -1 | pbcopy"`. You can quickly call that whenever you need to save a stroke of genius.

Comment: To remove the new line at the end of the copied command, you could run this command instead: "fc -ln -1 | tr -d '\n' | pbcopy"

Answer (score 1):

Client: pass the option `-XY` to the `ssh` command to enable (trusted) X11 forwarding for this session:

```
ssh -XY USER@IP
```

Server: check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to make sure X11 forwarding is enabled on server

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

```
yum install xclip -y
echo `hostname -I` `hostname` >> /etc/hosts
echo "alias cplastcmd='history 2 | cut -c 8- | head -n 1 | xclip -selection clipboard'" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Restart bash and type `cplastcmd` to copy last bash command to clipboard via X11.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following alias in `.zshrc` which I find quite helpful and it achieves the requirement quite smoothly.

```bash
# Function to execute before each command with your command as argument
function preexec() {
    PREV_COMMAND=$1
    # echo "Prev command: $PREV_COMMAND"
    echo "\$ $PREV_COMMAND" | pbcopy
}
```

#### The following might be useful to get some context

> Note: We are not using `precmd` here but might be useful in this context.

The `preexec` and `precmd` functions in Zsh are hooks that are invoked around the execution of a command line. They each serve different purposes:

1. `preexec`: This function is executed just before any command line is executed. It's commonly used for things like starting timers, manipulating the command that's about to be run, or recording the command for later use.
2. `precmd`: This function is executed before each prompt. It's often used for tasks that should be done before the user is prompted for the next command, such as printing information about the previous command, displaying Git branch information, or updating the title of the terminal.

To understand it better, think of the order of operations when you run a command in the terminal:

- You type a command and hit enter.
- The `preexec` function runs with your command as an argument.
- Your command is executed.
- The `precmd` function runs right before the next prompt is displayed.

The hooks give you an opportunity to run your own code at these specific points in the process. They're powerful tools for customizing your shell, and can be used to implement a wide variety of features.